# Replace substring in string using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, substring

I need to correct post address. I have a string `Miletičova 99/5b, 82108 Bratislava - Ružinov` and I need remove numbers before slash. Numbers can be from 1 to 999999.

Comment: To do this in php, you need to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know, but regext is for me magic :)

Comment: Please understand that this is not a coding service. I would recommend this site to develop the correct regex expression. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

`preg_replace('/(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]\d{0,5})\//', $string);` ([see example here](https://regex101.com/r/gWqaFc/3))

Comment: Thank you. Works.

Comment: @Meldo Remember to mark the question as being answered ;-)